# How to get descendants from current page in Umbraco 7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, umbraco, umbraco7

I have a document type with alias dArticlesMain, and for this page I have the following structure.

**dArticlesMain**

- dArticlesCategory1

  - Article1
  - Article2
  - Article3
- dArticlesCategory2

  - Article1
  - Article2
  - Article3
- dArticlesCategory3

  - Article1
  - Article2
  - Article3

I'm on dArticlesMain and i want to display all the descendants (Articles) and skip it's childrens (dArticlesCategory)

I have this code which display all the childrens (dArticlesCategory) and the descendants (Articles) also when i use the Article properties it's through an error.

```
<ul>
    @foreach(var page in Model.Content.Descendants())
    {
   <li><a href="@page.Url">@page.Name</a></li>
   }
</ul>
```

I have got this code but i can't display by Article properties like articleText or articleImage.

```
 <ul>
@foreach(var page in Model.Content.DescendantsOrSelf().OfTypes("Article"))
    {
        <li><a href="@page.Url">@page.Name</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out, and here's my code...

```
   @{ 
        var rootNode = CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(1);
        var articlesParent = rootNode.Children("dArticlesMain").FirstOrDefault();

        <div class="row">
            @foreach (var article in articlesParent.Descendants("article").Where("Visible").RandomOrder())
            {
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <a href="@article.Url">
                            <img src="@article.articlePhoto" alt="@article.articleName" />
                        </a>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <a class="h4" href="@article.Url">@article.articleName</a>
                            @Umbraco.Truncate(article.articleFullText, 100)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    }
```